# Gnome Glich | graphical interface error

Tags: gnome, interface

I really have no idea what has happened, Ubuntu has been working fine since I installed it, and just today, browsing the internet, it began to have errors when you showed images, first I thought it was the browser, but then, when I entered my game, I realized that the error was in everything, the details of the error, are images that do not display well. I would be very grateful if you would help me find what causes this failure, here is an image to see this error in more detail.

I started installing the interface, I already did everything, and it still does not solve it, please help!

[image]

Comment: Are you running 20.10 with kernel -49 or -50? Do `uname -r`.

Comment: 5.8.0-50-generic

Answer (score 0):

The -49 and -50 kernels are flawed, and have been withdrawn. There are graphics issues (possibly only with internal Intel video subsystems).

Boot your computer. At the GRUB menu, select the 2nd choice, Advanced Options (or some such), and select your -48 kernel, or earlier if you don't have -48, and run off of that for now.

Keep up to date with `Software Updater` and once you see the -51 kernel, or later, then choose it at next boot.

Comment: So ... I wait for the next kernel update?
only, my controller is generic ...

Comment: @AlejandroDawn Yes. Boot to -48. Then just wait until `Software Updater` shows kernel -51 or newer.